# how can i change the data that is under the CarouselSlider.builder when the CarouselSlider.builder is sliding

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bloc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV8nX.png)

```
how can i change the data that is under the slider when the slider is sliding
```

I've tried but got lost

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of slider and change the widgets like the following

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  double _currentSliderValue = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Slider(
          value: _currentSliderValue,
          max: 100,
          divisions: 5,
          label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
          onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              _currentSliderValue = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        (_currentSliderValue > 50)?
        Container(height:50, width: 100, color:Colors.red): 
        Container(height:50, width:100, color:Colors.green),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview1]

[image: preview2]

**EDIT**

in a carousel slider you have a method onChanged from where you get the index

```dart
CarouselSlider(
   items: imageSliders,
   carouselController: _controller,
    options: CarouselOptions(
    autoPlay: true,
    enlargeCenterPage: true,
    aspectRatio: 2.0,
    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
    setState(() {
      _current = index;//<----here
    });
  }),
),
```

based on the _current's value you can change widgets below it

Comment: how i add it in Carousel Slider.builder it's not available in parameter @kaushik-chandru

Comment: Edited my answer. Please add the correct names as Slider and Carousel Slider are two different widgets in Flutter

Comment: can you give a more detailed example? @kaushik-chandru

Comment: i tried it in stateles widget and it didn't work @kaushik-chandru

Comment: Setstate doesnt work in stateless widget

Comment: then what now?  – 
kaushik-chandru

Comment: Convert it to a stateful widget

Comment: how can i convert stateless to statefull @kaushik-chandra

Comment: Right click on stateless widget it will show convert to stateful widget